# Expected standard errors depend on the underlying distribution in regression

Tags: regression, r, random-variable, standard-error, convergence

I am investigating the effect of distributions of predictive variables ($x$) on their standard errors in regression. I thus programmed a little simulation to see how the standard errors behave. I used different distributions (normal, t, uniform, and log normal) as predictive variable in a regression model and looked at expected values of their standard errors at different (small) sample sizes. I made sure they had means of 0 and variance of 1 to make them more comparable.

```
set.seed(42)
N <- c(5:25)
nreps <- 10000
RES <- numeric()
beta <- .3

for(i in 1:length(N)){
  n <- N[i]
  out <- matrix(0, nreps, 4)
  for(k in 1:nreps){
    x.norm  <- rnorm(n)
    x.t     <- rt(n, df = 10)/sqrt(10/(10-2))
    x.unif  <- runif(n, -sqrt(3), sqrt(3))
    x.lnorm <-  rlnorm(n, -log(2)/2, sqrt(log(2)))-1 
    
    e <- rnorm(n) * sqrt(1-(beta^2))
    
    y.norm  <- beta * x.norm  + e
    y.t     <- beta * x.t     + e
    y.unif  <- beta * x.unif  + e
    y.lnorm <- beta * x.lnorm + e
    
    out[k,] <- c(summary(lm(y.norm  ~ x.norm))$coef[2,2],
                 summary(lm(y.t     ~ x.t))$coef[2,2],
                 summary(lm(y.unif  ~ x.unif))$coef[2,2],
                 summary(lm(y.lnorm ~ x.lnorm))$coef[2,2])
  }
  RES <- rbind(RES,
               data.frame(N = n,
                          dist =  c("norm","t","unif","lnorm"),
                          SE = colMeans(out)))
}

# Graph
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

RES %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = N, y = SE, color = dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

Here is the figure of the results.

[image]

So the questions are : Where does these differrences come from? Why are the standard errors converging differently? Why standard error is higher for some (lnorm) than other (unif)? Is their a way to compute and know beforehand how which one should converge based on the underlying distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by "converging differently"? Increase `N` to see that they converge to the same value. I would say this is related to influential data points (leverage). We usually recommend predictor values on a regular grid for linear regression (if the experimental setup allows this) and the uniform distribution results in something closest to that ideal whereas the (very skewed) log-normal distribution is farest away from it.

Comment: @Roland, I am sorry if I don't have the correct statistical terms. By "converging differently" I'm trying to convey their differences in rate. I have the intuition you mentionned, but what I would like is to compute the expected standard error. In all cases, the expected standard error would be the normal distribribution, $\sqrt{(1-\sigma^2)/(N-2)}$, but knowing the underlying distribution, is it possible to get a better estimate of the standard error?